# Custom arabic font working in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6 or earlier

Tags: ios, objective-c, arabic, uifont

I have an iPhone app where I am using custom arabic font.

All is working in iOS 7.

When I run the app on iOS 6, the text is appearing in default iPhone font.

Any idea what is going wrong?

### iOS 6 Screenshot

[image]

### iOS 7 Screenshot

[image]

***If you see the difference, english is working fine. ONLY PROBLEM WITH ARABIC FONT.***

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ : yes, I have ttf file...

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608573/how-to-add-custom-ttf-fonts-to-iphone-application

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ : english custom fonts works properly.. I have problem with Arabic fonts...

Comment: also show screenshot of info.plist along with code.. font name matters a lot..

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ : got solution... thanks for help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved...

```
UILabel *arTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 100)];
arTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
arTitle.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
arTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
arTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEDinarOne-Medium" size:16.0];
arTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
arTitle.text = @"واللقب هو عربي مع خط مخصص";

// these two line made effect...    
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:arTitle.text attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEDinarOne-Medium" size:16], NSLigatureAttributeName: @2}];

arTitle.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: +1 This also solved issues I was getting trying to embed the SS Standard font in iOS6: https://symbolset.com/icons/standard.